# Is there a easy way to identify which metric are global vs node specific?

Tags: ignite

As per the Ignite documentation below, There are two types of metrics Global and Node specific.

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring-metrics/intro

Is there a easy way to identify which metric are global vs node specific on below page?

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring-metrics/new-metrics

Currently I have to guess to see if metric value is same from different reporting nodes, hence its global otherwise its node specific. There should be some easy way to find out.
It would be nice to have another column in the documentation showing global vs node specific.